# What is a fraction in which the greatest common factor of the numerator and the denominator is 1?

Tags: terminology, definition, rational-numbers

What is this fraction:

A fraction in which the greatest common factor of the numerator and the denominator is 1?

Comment: The **bold** formatting and multiple question marks (??) are not necessary, and make your questions harder to read. I have removed them from this question, and I would ask that you do not use them in the future.

Answer (score 6):

A fraction in which the greatest common factor of the numerator and the denominator is 1 is known as a **reduced, or simplified, fraction.** $$\dfrac 68 \;\;\text{is not reduced (or not simplified) because}  \;\dfrac 68 = \dfrac {\color{blue}{\bf 2}\cdot 3} {\color{blue}{\bf 2}\cdot 2\cdot 2}$$

$$\dfrac 34\;\;\text{ is a reduced, or simplified, fraction:}\;\dfrac {\color{blue}{\bf 1}\cdot 3}{\color{blue}{\bf 1}\cdot 2\cdot 2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Quite often I have also heard this called a *fraction in its lowest terms*.

Answer (score 0):

This just means that the fraction has been reduced. For instance $4/6$ is not such a fraction, because the top and the bottom have gcf = 2, but $2/3$ is such a fraction.

Another way of saying it is that numerator and denominator are *coprime*.

Answer (score 0):

In Common Core math book it is "Simplest Form."